# where to set the original data folder

Tags: php, symfony4

I have symfony4 project.

I need to handle some csv file, so I made myAppCsv folder under the main directory.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $finder = new Finder();
    $finder->in(array('myAppCsv'));
```

then I access folder from command like this.

```
$ php bin/console app:getcsv
```

it works well when you exec in main directory.

Now, I want to use the same command from commandline (test for crontab)

```
/usr/local/bin/php /Users/whitebear/httproot/myApp/bin/console app:getcsv
```

it shows error.

```
The "myAppCsv" directory does not exist.
```

Where should I put my original data directory and hw to handle??

Comment: When passing `myAppCsv`, use an absolute path to that as well: `__DIR__ . '/myAppCsv'`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I had this in mind, but `__DIR__` will be the path of the script

Comment: Yes, `__DIR__` will be the path of the script. That's why you can use it. Then you have a proper starting point. If the folder isn't located in the same folder as the script, you should do `__DIR__ .'/path/to/folder` or `__DIR__ . '/../path/to/folder` depending on your needs

Comment: `__DIR__` returns the path of command folder so, I use `__DIR__/../../myAppCsv`. From /src/Command/DefaultCommand.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path as absolute. You can use `__DIR__` contant or `kernel.root_dir` parameter.

I prefer using the `kernel.root_dir` in case you have to move the command in another folder.

You will have the absolute path to the folder, for example, something like:

```
$finder->in(
    array(
        sprintf('%s/../myAppCsv', $this->rootDir)
    )
);
```

With rootDir getting from dependency injection or container

Comment: Thank you very much! for now, I don't need to move command directory so I use `__DIR__`